# Why does C# constructor behavior differ from Java, or vice versa?

Tags: java, c#, constructor

Given this Java code, this outputs **0 and 4**:

```
class A{
   A() {  print();   }
   void print() { System.out.println("A"); }
}

class B extends A{
   int i =   Math.round(3.5f); 
    
   public static void main(String[] args){
      A a = new B();
      a.print();
   }
   void print() { System.out.println(i); }
}
```

And with this identical C# code, this outputs **4 and 4**

```
using System;

class A{
   internal A() {  print();   }
   virtual internal void print() { Console.WriteLine("A"); }
}

class B : A{
   int i =  (int) Math.Round(3.5f); 
    
   public static void Main(string[] args){
      A a = new B();
      a.print();
   }
   override internal void print() { Console.WriteLine(i); }
}
```

Though I figure out that the output should be 4 and 4 on Java, but the answer is actually 0 and 4 on Java. Then I tried it in C#, the answer is 4 and 4

What gives? Java rationale is, during construction of B, A is still initializing(consequently I posit B is still initializing if Java said A is still initializing), so the default value should be 0. Hence the output is 0 and 4 in Java.

***Why does C# constructor behavior differ from Java, or vice versa?***

Comment: I'll let other people answer the "why", but these sorts of problems is why it's generally considered poor practice to call virtual methods from constructors.

Comment: +1 for considering calling a virtual methods from constructor a poor practice. The output is not predictable given different languages have different design philosophy

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I feel that too. I wanted to come up with a solution though. How to make the code intent clearer or code behavior predictable, given the languages' nuances. There may not be clear-cut solution to this problem, but there maybe some best practices around, e.g. ruling that virtual method should not be called in constructor

Comment: @Hao - Why don't you add a real example of this behavior difference causing problems?

Comment: @Hao: My statement was not meant to imply that the question was unworthy, and in fact far from this, but rather just that it probably does not belong here. Perhaps [programmers stack exchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) is a better fit.

Comment: This may be of some use for the C# side of things: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/02/15/why-do-initializers-run-in-the-opposite-order-as-constructors-part-one.aspx

Comment: @mike z - Actually that explains it completely.

Comment: @ChaosPandion Here's a real example of that behavior.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10850037/how-to-handle-initialization-of-variables-under-specified-circumstances Many people(including Jon Skeet) advises not to call an overrideable(which sadly is the default) method from the constructor

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's happening because of differences in the ordering of object initialisation in constructors.

What is happening in Java:

- (empty, implicit) Constructor of B is called
- Superclass Construtor of A is called (prints 0 since i is uninitialised)
- i is initialised *after* the superclass constructor
- print() is called (prints 4)

What is happening in C#:

- (empty, implicit) Constructor of B is called
- i is initialised *before* calling the superclass constructor
- Superclass Construtor of A is called (prints 4 since i is already initialised)
- print() is called (prints 4)

Neither is right or wrong - it's just a difference in how the compiler orders the construction operations. Personally I think the Java ordering is a marginally more logical, because it makes sense to me that the superclass is fully constructed before the subclass initialisation takes place.

Either way, because the logic can get quite complicated, I'd suggest that you avoid calling virtual methods during object construction in general.

Comment: I try to debug for the Java and just know the step by step how the program has been execute, but unfortunately I didn't have C# compiler. +1 for the pseudo-code.

Comment: @Hao: Nice one, but no Debug function :-)

Comment: @mikera C# ***could emulate*** Java's behavior though ( 0 and 4 ). leave the initializer empty, just a variable declaration only (i.e. `int i;`), then move the assignment to B's constructor: `internal B() { i =   Math.round(3.5f);  }`.  The other way around is not possible though, i.e. Java could not be work-around'd to make it output 4 and 4

Comment: Re: "avoid calling virtual methods during object construction in general" That's truly true. The following question confirms my suspicion, sigh... **Java's constructor is not a one-stop-shop**  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10850037/how-to-handle-initialization-of-variables-under-specified-circumstances

Answer (score 1):

The order of initialization in Java:

1.The storage of the instance is wiped to zero, automatically setting all the primitives in the object to their default values (zero for numbers and the equivalent for boolean and char) and the references to null.

2.The constructor of the base `class A` is called. It will the call the `print` method in `class B`, since it is an overridden method. `i` is 0 at this moment.

3.The member initialization of the class B is executed. So `i` is 4 now.

In order not to produce this kind of surprise, do not call any non-static or non-private methods in a constructor,since they may be overridden in derived classes.