# How to handle initialization of variables under specified circumstances

Tags: java, swing, oop, refactoring, initialization

I have a class whose constructor looks something like below:

```
abstract class BasePanel extends JPanel {
  public BasePanel(A a) {
    // initializing fields from values passed to ctor
    this.a = a;
    // initializing gui components
    initializeComponents();
    setupPanels();
    concludeUiSetup();
  }

  // stuff
}
```

In the constructor, first the fields that are to be initialized with values passed to constructor are initialized. Then other methods required for UI setup are called in order. Two of these methods need to be overridden in subclass for UI setup specific to them.

Now consider a class `FooPanel` that extends `BasePanel`. It requires a few more initialization parameters in its constructor.

```
class FooPanel extends BasePanel {
  public FooPanel(A a, B b) {
    super(a);
    this.b = b;
  }

  @Override
  public void initializeComponents() {
    super.initializeComponents();
    // I require b here, but oops, b is not initialized at this point, and so 
    // this will throw NPE.
    someTextField.setText(b.get());
  }

  // stuff
}
```

`initializeComponents` method here requires `b`, which unfortunately is not initialized at that point.

What would be the appropriate way to restructure this code so that:

- the fields required are set before they're needed.
- the code that uses `FooPanel` (and other panels) isn't cluttered to much by this change.

Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: why is `b` not initialized? it gets passed inside the constructor.

Comment: erm, have a `init()` method to initialize stuff? And by the principle of high cohesion, `init()` fits the bid?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen because `initializeComponents` is called by `super(a)` before b has been set.

Comment: What @KazekageGaara said, use the constructors to set the values, then do initialization by calling an init() method.

Comment: @assylias Yes, and that initializes the fields of the superclass. B shouldnt be initialized in the superclass since it is not a member there

Comment: And I think you should look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2529618/828625) answer. It says that "Constructors must not invoke overridable methods, directly or indirectly".

Comment: You should not call an overridable method in the constructor.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen `FooPanel(a,b)` -> `super(a)` -> `BasePanel(a)` -> **`FooPanel#initializecomponents`** -> NPE

Comment: I'm always a bit wary when I see code trying to use inheritance on a GUI widget. This is a very tricky thing to do, and is often a misuse of inheritance. I'm not saying that's the case here, but if I were the one reviewing your code, it would set off alarms, and I'd want to see something justifying this.

Comment: @KazekageGaara, thanks for answering Hunter's question for me, and thanks for the thread link. By the way, I am also a Naruto fan. :)

Comment: @Brady, thanks. I think that would be more appropriate as an answer.

Comment: @BheshGurung, thanks. I think that would be more appropriate as an answer.

Comment: @missingfaktor, if you're suggesting I enter another answer, I think KazekageGaara should get the credit, since he/she said it first, I just formalized it :)

Comment: encountered the same error in Java, doesn't happen in C# though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611726/java-constructor-is-not-so-intuitive-or-perhaps-its-not-java-its-c-sharp-tha

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should not call overridable methods from a constructor. What you should do, in this case, is defining a constructor that only initializes instance fields, and put the initialization of the GUI in an overridable initialize() method, which is not called from the constructor.

So, to construct a FooPanel, you do:

```
FooPanel p = new FooPanel(a, b);
p.initialize();
```

And if you won't force all the clients of FooPanel to do that, you define the constructor private, and provide  a factory method:

```
public static FooPanel create(A a, B b) {
    FooPanel p = new FooPanel(a, b);
    p.initialize();
    return p;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I independently came up with the same solution. It appears, , in this context, one cannot do anything more cleaner with Java.

Answer (score 5):

Basically, try to avoid calling virtual (i.e. overridable) methods within constructors. It causes exactly this sort of problem. If you're going to call a virtual method in a constructor, you need to document it - and quite possibly avoid calling it anywhere else. Such a method has to be written to handle the object not being fully initialized yet, which puts it in an awkward spot.

It's hard to know more specific advice to give without more information, but I'd also encourage you to embrace composition over inheritance where possible - or at least always consider it, and decide on the most elegant approach.

If you really want inheritance here, do you really need `initializeComponents` at all? Can't each class do its own initialization within its own constructor, without relying on anything from its subclass state?

Comment: Thanks for the advice regarding overridable methods. As for object composition, looking at the big picture (which is not described in my post), that would be a very wrong way to go about it. Re: `initializeComponents`, the classes have a lot in common, and avoiding inheritance here would cause a lot of code duplication.

Comment: @missingfaktor: Okay, maybe you want to use inheritance - but that still doesn't explain why you need to initialize everything within an overridden method. Why can't each class perform its own initialization within its constructor (or a private method called directly from its constructor)? As I say, the approach you've got is simply going to cause you problems. It's a known anti-pattern, and is almost *never* the best approach.

Comment: That will require each class to call those methods in order, thus causing obvious duplication, and making code more error-prone. I think I am going with JB's solution here.

Comment: @missingfaktor: Each class only needs to work out how to initialize *itself*. You get *local* complexity that's easy to reason about. Compare that with forcing *every* caller to call `initialize` before doing anything - which leads to global complexity. I really dislike classes which aren't really valid after the constructor returns. Ick. But it's your call, of course...